# Non-empty intersection of infinitely many subsets in Finite measure space

Tags: measure-theory

Question is: Let $(X,\sum,\mu)$ be a finite measure space. Prove that if $A_n \in \sum$ and for every $n$ we have $\mu(A_n)\geq\epsilon>0$ then there is $x \in X$ such that $x \in A_n$ for infinitely many $n$.

My attempt: If $A_n$ is infinite sequence of sets with property $\mu(A_n)\geq\epsilon$ then $\sum_{i=1}^\infty\mu(A_i)=\infty$.
But because of $\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_n \subseteq X$ , we have $\mu(\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_n) \leq \mu(X) < \infty $.
Since $\mu(\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_n)<\sum_{i=1}^\infty\mu(A_i)$ we know that $A_n$ is not sequence of disjoint sets.

From that moment i have a problem with proving that there exist infinite subsequence of $A_n$ with no empty intersection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set $B_k := \bigcup_{n \geq k} A_n$, then $\mu(B_k) \geq \mu(A_k) \geq \epsilon$. Moreover, $B_k \downarrow B:= \bigcap_{k \geq 1} B_k$ (the arrow indicates that the sequence is decreasing, i.e. $B_{k+1} \subseteq B_k$ for all $k$). By the continuity of the (finite!) measure $\mu$,  we get

$$\mu(B) = \lim_{k \to \infty} \mu(B_k) \geq \epsilon>0.$$

In particular, $B \neq \emptyset$, and so we can pick $x \in B$. By the definition of $B$, this means that $x \in A_n$ for infinitely many $n \in \mathbb{N}$.